# Is there a way to assign macro variable to output of SAS data set based on if condition?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to know if there is a way to extract output out of a SAS table based on an if statement and then assign that output to a macro variable?

I've already tried the below code but it doesn't work

```
      /*Working*/
      libname param '<directory>'; /*contain parameter table*/

      data _null_;
          set PARAM.RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL_MP;
          call symput('task_id', task_id);
        call symput('functionality', functionality);
        call symput('parameter', parameter);
        call symput('value', value);
        put task_id= functionality= parameter= value= ;
      run;

      /*Not Working*/

      data _null_;
      set PARAM.RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL (where=(TASK_ID='&task_id.' and           FUNCTIONALITY='&functionality.' )); 

      if parameter='mnthly'         then call symput('mnthly',mnthly);
 else if parameter='emailsubject'   then call symput('emailsubject',emailsubject);
 else if parameter='emailrecipient' then call symput('emailrecipient',emailrecipient);
 else if parameter='emailcc'        then call symput('emailcc',emailcc);
 else if parameter='content_type'   then call symput('contenttype',contenttype);
 else if parameter='attach'         then call symput('attach',attach);
 else if parameter='finyrs'         then call symput('finyrs',finyrs);
 else if parameter='ext_dt'         then call symput('ext_dt',ext_dt);

 title="TASK1045V2 Benefit Type summary for last &finyrs years. NOTE: YEAR extends from "||
       substr(put(&ext_dt+1),3,3)||' to '||substr(put(&ext_dt),3,3);
       call symput('title',trim(title)) ;

       /*view results in Log file. It shouldn't be blank*/
       put mnthly= emailsubject= emailrecipient= emailcc= content_type=      attach= finyrs= ext_dt= title= ; 
 run;
```

My SAS table RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL_MP is in photo attached.

[RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL_MP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xut5u.png)

I basically want to assign the macro variable 'mthly' with value of 'parameter' column when parameter = 'mthly' ; macro variable 'emailsubject' with value of 'parameter' column when parameter = 'emailsubject' etc.

Comment: Please post your sample data as text, not as a picture of text. Edit your question and add it at the bottom.

Also, please post a [minimal, complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of the code that causes the problem. Someone should be able to copy and paste your code into a new SAS session and get exactly the same problem.

Comment: Also, it seems like the photo shows the data set used in the first data step, not the data set used in the data step that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as show appears to be wonky.  The `set` statement

```
set PARAM.RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL (where=(TASK_ID='&task_id.' and …
```

does it return on one row or several (one per parameter)?

If multiple I would expect the structure and content to be

```
      task_id functionality parameter    parameter_value
      ------- ------------- ---------    ---------------
row 1 ttttt   fffff         mnthly       xxxx
row 2 ttttt   fffff         emailsubject yyyy
…                           … 
      ttttt   fffff         ext_dt       zzzz
```

and not (as the code suggests)

```
      task_id functionality parameter    mnthly  emailsubject … ext_dt
      ------- ------------- ---------    ------  ------------ … ------
row 1 ttttt   fffff         mnthly       xxxx
row 2 ttttt   fffff         emailsubject         yyyy
…                           … 
      ttttt   fffff         ext_dt                               zzzz
```

Regardless,

`SYMGET` is used to retrieve the current value of a macro variable while the data step is running.  The retrieved value can not be resolved using `&` to affect the source code of a running step.

So, `&` in code such as:

```
 … 
 else if parameter='finyrs'         then call symput('finyrs',finyrs);
 else if parameter='ext_dt'         then call symput('ext_dt',ext_dt);

 title="TASK1045V2 Benefit Type summary for last &finyrs years. NOTE: YEAR extends from "||
       substr(put(&ext_dt+1),3,3)||…
```

would be restated as

```
 … 
 else if parameter='finyrs'         then call symput('finyrs',finyrs);
 else if parameter='ext_dt'         then call symput('ext_dt',ext_dt);

 title="TASK1045V2 Benefit Type summary for last " 
       || symget('finyrs') || years. NOTE: YEAR extends from "
       || substr(put(     symget('ext_dt')   +1),3,3) || …
```

However, you might want to rethink the strategy.

Run the step part with the `SYMPUT`s first, in order to populate the macro variables, then in a second step have

```
data _null_;
  … symputs … 
run;

* populated macro variables can be resolved with & in title assignment source code;
data _null_;
  title="TASK1045V2 Benefit Type summary for last &finyrs years. NOTE: YEAR extends from "||
       substr(put(&ext_dt+1),3,3)||' to '||substr(put(&ext_dt),3,3);
       call symput('title',trim(title)) ;

       /*view results in Log file. It shouldn't be blank*/
       put mnthly= emailsubject= emailrecipient= emailcc= content_type=      attach= finyrs= ext_dt= title= ; 
 run;
```

A further alternative would be to `retain` the parameter variable values in the data step PDV instead of storing them in the macro symbol table.  The approach used is dependent on the actual **parameter table data structure**

**If** the actual structure is one row such as

```
      task_id functionality parameter    mnthly  emailsubject … ext_dt
      ------- ------------- ---------    ------  ------------ … ------
row 1 ttttt   fffff         mnthly       xxxx    yyyy         … zzzz
```

then the multiple ifs you coded are not needed, and the symput to macro variables is not needed, just use the data set variables already in the PDV when assigning the `title=`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by assigning the values in column "VALUE" into values in "PARAMETER" as the macro name?

if so this should get you what you need

```
data _null_;
set PARAM.RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL_MP;
call symput(parameter, value);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in quoting macro-variables. If you want to compare value of character variable with macro parameter, you should use `"&macro_var"`, not `'&macro_var'`.

So, fix `where` statement in data step:

```
set PARAM.RPTAUTO_PARAMETERTBL (where=(TASK_ID="&task_id." and FUNCTIONALITY="&functionality." ));
```